# Determine if asp.net application support load balancing environment

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing

I am new to asp.net, I have been tasked to upgrade the physical architecture to load balancing environment to support the application.

I done some reading the session state should be configure to Out-Process instead of In-Proc to support load balancing.

Is there any other issues I need to take note for asp.net web application to run in the load balanced environment?

Comment: try searching for it
http://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net+web+farm&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are going to have your session out of proc, your session objects should be serializable. If you want a quick solution, sticky sessions are an option. You can read about it [here](http://daveonsoftware.blogspot.com/2007/08/load-balancer-persistence-sticky.html)

Comment: This can be a big issue if you're using third party objects.

Comment: how so ?The client only "talks to" one web server for the lifetime of the session.